# Translate 3D cube on x-axis

Tags: javascript, matrix, 3d, webgl

Im trying to translate two 3D cubes away from each other. I've tried using the clipspace aswell as the translation matrix but nothing has worked. The solution im looking for is the cubes side-by-side preferably on the x-axis.

Here is my code:

```js
var gl,program,canvas;

var vBuffer, vPosition;
var idxBuffer;

var vertices = [
    -0.5, 0.5, 1,
     0.5, 0.5, 1,
     0.5, -0.5, 1,
    -0.5, -0.5, 1,
    -0.5, 0.5, 0,
     0.5, 0.5, 0,
     0.5, -0.5, 0,
    -0.5, -0.5, 0
];

var dVecIdx = new Uint16Array([
  0, 1, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 3, 0,
  4, 5, 5, 6,
        6, 7, 7, 4,
  0, 4, 1, 5,
        2, 6, 3, 7
]);

var projection = [
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 1
];

var a = Math.sqrt(0.5);
var rotation = [
   a, 0, a, 0,
   0, 1, 0, 0,
  -a, 0, a, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 1
];

window.onload = function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
    if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn't available"); }

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");

    vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    idxBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, idxBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, dVecIdx, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    render();
}

function render() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.useProgram(program);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    projLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "projectionMatrix");
    loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "rotate");
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, false, projection);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc, false, projection);
    gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, dVecIdx.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    projLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "projectionMatrix");
    loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "rotate");
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, false, projection);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc, false, rotation);
    gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, dVecIdx.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/MV.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>

    <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 vPosition;
        attribute vec4 vColor;
        varying vec4 fColor;
        uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
        uniform mat4 rotate;

        void main() {
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * rotate * vec4(vPosition, 1);
            fColor = vColor;
        }
    </script>

    <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        varying vec4 fColor;

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = fColor;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="border: 1px dotted black;">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try getting too much more advanced with your setup I would recommend either using a WebGL library such as Three.js to abstract away some of the math or really taking the time to google around and understand object and camera transformation matrices.

### Answer:

Having said that, the simple answer is to just add another matrix for translations and insert it between your projection and rotation matrix in the shader:

```
attribute vec3 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 rotate;
uniform mat4 translate;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * translate * rotate * vec4(vPosition, 1);
    fColor = vColor;
}
```

The translation matrix will look like:

```
var translation = [
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    x, y, z, 1
];
```

where `x`, `y`, and `z` are the translation distances along the X-axis, Y-axis, and Z-axis respectively.
This would then be added to the render method in the same way as the rotation matrix:

```
transLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "translate");
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(transLoc, false, translation);
```

### Optimizations:

Now also having said *that*, there are a few more optimizations/corrections you can make:

**1)** Since WebGL maintains its "state" until changed (keeps things bound/set/enabled/etc.), you can remove a lot of the repeated code in your `render()` method:

```
function render() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set state
    gl.useProgram(program);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    projLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "projectionMatrix");
    loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "rotate");
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, false, projection);

    // draw shape 1
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc, false, projection);
    gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, dVecIdx.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // draw shape 2
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc, false, rotation);
    gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, dVecIdx.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

**2)** If you don't want to use a specific matrix during rendering you should set it to the identity matrix which doesn't change other matrices/vectors when multiplied:

```
var identity = [
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
];
```

This is what you should use for the rotation matrix on your first shape instead of the perspective matrix:

```
// draw shape 1
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(loc, false, identity);
gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, dVecIdx.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

**3)** You can declare the progLoc, rotLoc, and transLoc as global variables and set their values as soon as the program is initialized. These won't change for a single program and don't need to be reset in the render loop.

```
program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
projLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "projectionMatrix");
rotLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "rotate");
transLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "translate");
```

Making the final code:

```js
var gl,program,canvas;

var vBuffer, vPosition;
var idxBuffer;
var projLoc, rotLoc, transLoc;


var vertices = [
    -0.5, 0.5, 1,
     0.5, 0.5, 1,
     0.5, -0.5, 1,
    -0.5, -0.5, 1,
    -0.5, 0.5, 0,
     0.5, 0.5, 0,
     0.5, -0.5, 0,
    -0.5, -0.5, 0
];

var dVecIdx = new Uint16Array([
  0, 1, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 3, 0,
  4, 5, 5, 6,
        6, 7, 7, 4,
  0, 4, 1, 5,
        2, 6, 3, 7
]);

var identity = [
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
];

var projection = [
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 1,
    0, 0, 0, 1
];

var a = Math.sqrt(0.5);
var rotation = [
   a, 0, a, 0,
   0, 1, 0, 0,
  -a, 0, a, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 1
];

// actual translations are set in the render() function
var translation = [
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1
];


window.onload = function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");

    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
    if (!gl) { alert("WebGL isn't available"); }

    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    gl.clearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    projLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "projectionMatrix");
    rotLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "rotate");
    transLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "translate");

    vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    idxBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, idxBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, dVecIdx, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    render();
}

function render() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set non-changing states
    gl.useProgram(program);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, false, projection);
    
    // draw shape 1
    translation[12] = 1; // x-axis translation (y and z are 0)
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(transLoc, false, translation);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(rotLoc, false, identity);
    gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, dVecIdx.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // draw shape 2
    translation[12] = -1; // set x-axis translation
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(transLoc, false, translation);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(rotLoc, false, rotation);
    gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, dVecIdx.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/MV.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/WebGL/7E/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>

    <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 vPosition;
        attribute vec4 vColor;
        varying vec4 fColor;
        uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
        uniform mat4 rotate;
        uniform mat4 translate;

        void main() {
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * translate * rotate * vec4(vPosition, 1);
            fColor = vColor;
        }
    </script>

    <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        varying vec4 fColor;

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = fColor;
        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="border: 1px dotted black;">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <canvas id="gl-canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**4)** If you want to use your `MV.js` script you can also declare your matrices as `mat4()` objects and use `mult()` to multiply the matrices on the CPU before transferring data to the GPU (one multiplication per shape instead of one per vertex). You can also use it to create more versatile and accurate camera matrices:

```
var persp = perspective(30.0, 1, 0.1, 100); // fovy, aspect, near, far
var view = lookAt([0, 0, 5], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]); // eye, look, up
var projection2D = mult(persp, view);

var projection = []; // convert to 1D array
for(var i = 0; i < projection2D.length; i++) {
    projection = projection.concat(projection2D[i]);
}
```

Hope this is helpful! Cheers!